# Error:(19, 21) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to item

Tags: java

I'm writing a program using Jaxb to convert an xml file into a java object. However, in my main class, I'm extending my item class to my items class to get access to the data stored in there, but it's telling me that it requires an object and it received an item instead. I'm a bit confused. When I build the file I get the error message in the title.

Here's my main class-- I'm getting the error in the for loop for **item**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException {
        File file = new File("items.xml");

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(items.class);
        Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
        items itemData = (items) un.unmarshal(file);

        List items = itemData.getitem();

        for(item e: items){
            System.out.println("DataType : "+e.getDataType());
            System.out.println("Name : "+e.getName());
            System.out.println("Data : "+e.getData());
            System.out.println("Group : "+e.getGroup());
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my item class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class item {
    private String dataType;
    private String name;
    private int data;
    private String group;

    @XmlElement
    public String getDataType(){
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType){
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getGroup(){
        return group;
    }
    public void setGroup(String group){
        this.group = group;
    }
}
```

Here is my items class

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class items {
    private List<item> item;

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<item> getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<item> itemList){
        this.item = itemList;
    }
}
```

Here is my xml file

```
<items> 
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Harry Potter 1</name>
            <data>5</data>
            <group>Movie</group>
      </item>
      <item>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <name>Harry Potter 2</name>
            <data>6</data>
            <group>Movies</group>
            <items>
                  <item>
                        <dataType>Number</dataType>
                        <name>Harry Potter 3</name>
                        <data>7</data>
                        <group>Books</group>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                        <dataType>Number</dataType>
                        <name>Harry Potter 4</name>
                        <data>8</data>
                        <group>Books</group>
                  </item>
            </items>
      </item>
</items>
```

Comment: post your xml file and source code of `items.class`

Comment: Class name in item and not items , Please change this JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(items.class); to JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(item.class);

Comment: xml file was posted

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi the change was made but it still gives me the error. Shouldn't it be items though? Since items though is the parent of the child item?

Comment: PLease check this https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-unmarshaller-example/ , everywhere you have written items , but your class name is item .

Comment: I have another class name for items, I didn't post it since I thought the error resided in the item class

Comment: I see element <items> can be nested within <item>. Harry Petter 3 and 4 are nested within 2. Is it expected?

Comment: It's a project I'm doing actually, that's the format I was given to follow so yes, it's expected

Comment: Post was modified, the items class and xml file was added.

Comment: Not really related to your question, nonetheless I feel it is important to make you aware. Code is read much more often than it is written and read by many people, not just its author. That's why most people follow java naming conventions when writing code - because it makes it easier for others to read and understand. Class names should begin with a capital letter. Class `main` should be `Main`. Class `item` should be `Item`. And class `items` should be `Items`.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
List items = itemData.gettem();
```

to

```
List<item> items = itemData.getItem();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as answered by Anique Azhar, fix your compilation error from

```java
List items = itemData.getitem();
```

to

```java
List<item> items = itemData.getItem();
```

Secondly, as said by Abra in the question comment, The class name should be Capitalized.

Then to handle the element `<items>` nested in `<item>`, add a field `items` of class `Items` to class `Item`.

```java
public class Item {
    private String dataType;
    private String name;
    private int data;
    private String group;
    private Items items;
    
    // getter and setter
}
```

My working code is available in [Github](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/so62749048). See the [commit history](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/so62749048/commits/master) for what I did based on your code.

Your programming journey is long. Keep on. Take some time to learn [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). Next time ask question on stackoverflow, better share your code in Github. It make people locate the problem faster.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it's very much appreciated. I made the following changes and it worked, partially. I'm not getting to display the nested items "harry potter 3 and 4" are not displaying

Comment: I'm currently checking the github to see if your code deals with my problem above

Comment: @SharleneRoberts If you run my latest code, the output of Harry Poter 2 should be DataType : Number
Name : Harry Potter 2
Data : 6
Group : Movies
Nested items : Items{item=[Item{dataType='Number', name='Harry Potter 3', data=7, group='Books', items=null}, Item{dataType='Number', name='Harry Potter 4', data=8, group='Books', items=null}]}

Comment: Check github since I seem to be running into a problem with running the code. I went through it however I saw what you mentioned above. Thanks a ton